# Sublime text HTMLPrettify - disable formatting *.min.* files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am using [**HTMLPrettify**](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify) with formatting set to "on save". Everytime I open and change the contents of a minified file, the package simply expands it and formats it the way it has to be, but that is not what I want. I want to exclude all files that have *.min.* in their extensions, so they can remain minified on save.

How can I do this?

> **SOLUTION:** As **[MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426065/mattdmo)** explained in his solution, there is no setting comming out of the box for this [**HTMLPrettify**](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting to do this. However, if you feel comfortable editing the plugin's code, you can do the following. Select **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** to open your `Packages` folder in your operating system's file manager. Navigate to the `HTMLPrettify` folder and open `HTMLPrettify.py` in Sublime.

Go to line 22, which should be a comment on the very first line of the `run` method in the `HtmlprettifyCommand` class. Put your cursor just before the `#` symbol and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a few times to insert some blank lines. Then, go back to the very beginning of first blank line (not the indented beginning, the *very* beginning of the line) and insert the following code (the indentation should already be correct):

```py
    from os.path import split
    try:
      if ".min." in split(self.view.file_name())[1]:
        return
    except TypeError:
      pass
```

Save the file, and the plugin should reload automatically. You can always restart Sublime to make sure. To explain the code: first we import [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split), which separates the filename from the rest of the path. Next, we try to see if the string `.min.` is in the filename (`os.path.split()` returns a 2-part tuple containing the full path at the 0 index, and the filename at the 1 index). If it is, we [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) the method, ensuring that it does nothing else. If the string is not found, the code just continues on like normal. A [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) exception may be raised by `split()` if [`self.view.file_name()`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View) doesn't contain anything, which would be the case if you're working in an unnamed buffer. If the `TypeError` does occur, we catch it and [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement), as it means there is no `.min.` in the filename.

### Warning

With this change, the plugin will no longer work on *any* minified file with `.min.` in the filename, even if you **want** to un-minify it. You'll either have to copy the contents to a blank buffer or rename the file first.

Good luck!